# How do I search for something other than User?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

In Google Cloud Platform/Datastore/Entities with Kind being "User" I'm shown the first 50 User keys (which I can search for successfully with a filter on Key), and next to each User key is displayed the value of an entity "gaeUser", which is a string such as Joe@gmail.com. I click 'Filter Entities" and from the dropdown menu I choose "gaeUser". This automatically sets up "is a string equal to", and in the last box I enter 'Joe.gmail.com', which is one of the values of gaeUser shown in the previous display. I am returned "No entities matched this query". I have of course also tried double quote marks or none, with no success. I really need to be able to do such searches, and I can't imagine why I can't. Help?

Answer (score 0):

A screen shot of the unfiltered results showing `gaeUser` would be useful to see.

Possible issues:

- the property `gaeUser` is not indexed
- the property `gaeUser` is not type String, but something else
- the value `Joe@gmail.com` has whitespace in it like a `\r\n`

EDIT: Added screenshot. If you click on a specific entity in the datastore viewer and then click on a property, it will tell you it's type.
[image]

EDIT 2:

Hmm, embedded entity. I think you need to search the field `gaeUser.email` If the dropdown UI doesnt provide that field for you maybe try QUERY BY GQL instead of QUERY BY KIND

```
SELECT * From `User` where gaeUser.email='gork@gleep.org'
```

Comment: I wasn't able to figure out how to post an image. There is no white space in the gaeUser elements, which are email addresses. I assume that they are strings, but what else could they be? Perhaps the problem is that they aren't "indexed"; what is necessary for an element to be indexed? What would I have to do to index them?

Comment: Concerning indexing, I read this in a Google doc: "Indexes for simple queries, such as queries over a single property, are created automatically." I think I'm only making a query over a single property, gaeUser....??

Comment: Note that I AM able to search on Key.

Comment: I added a screenshot to my answer. Click on one of your entities and then click on your property and see what it tells you. It will tell you if the property is indexed, it'll also tell you it's type. You want it to be `String`, but maybe it's type `Text` or `Blob` or even `Key`. To index a property, I specify it in my ORM. I use `ndb` in python

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! That's very helpful, as I had never clicked the right things to get to the page you show. What i see is that gaeUser is in fact indexed, but its type is "embedded entity", whatever that is. I'm also shown the code below. Can I change the type from "embedded entity" to "string" without destroying the datastore? How should I proceed? (I know that this isn't an answer, and that I shouldn't be posting an answer, but I have no idea how to display code intelligibly without using the answer input mechanism (where I see that one can also post an image).

```
{
  "properties": {
    "auth_domain": {
      "stringValue": "gmail.com",
      "excludeFromIndexes": true
    },
    "user_id": {
      "stringValue": "1114935",
      "excludeFromIndexes": true
    },
    "email": {
      "stringValue": "gork@gleep.org",
      "excludeFromIndexes": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So you need to query on the field `gaeUser.email`. See `EDIT 2` in my answer

Comment: Thanks. Will do.

Comment: if my answer worked, then mark it as correct so that future people know